# Rejected all local requests

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

Periodically something strange happens with our VM.

At some point it's not possible to send request to services. Even if consul or redis are working, got timeout error:

```
consul members
Error connecting to Consul agent: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8400: getsockopt: connection timed out
```

and

```
/usr/local/src/redis-3.0.7/src/redis-cli -p 6379
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection timed out
```

But if I restart firewall with `apf -r` it will work.

I've saved iptables rules into file before restarting apf, found few strange rules:

```
Chain RESET (0 references)
pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination 
0 0 REJECT tcp -- * * 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 reject-with tcp-reset

Chain PROHIBIT (0 references)
pkts bytes target prot opt in out source destination 
0 0 REJECT all -- * * 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

100% sure that I haven't added this rules. The only one thing I've found in logs:

```
Jul 15 06:25:01 journey-test python3[1090]: 2018/07/15 06:25:01.935420 INFO Successfully added Azure fabric firewall rules
Jul 15 06:25:01 journey-test python3[1090]: 2018/07/15 06:25:01.963119 INFO Firewall rules:
Jul 15 06:25:01 journey-test python3[1090]: Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
Jul 15 06:25:01 journey-test python3[1090]:     pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
Jul 15 06:25:01 journey-test python3[1090]: Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
Jul 15 06:25:01 journey-test python3[1090]:     pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
Jul 15 06:25:01 journey-test python3[1090]: Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
Jul 15 06:25:01 journey-test python3[1090]:     pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
Jul 15 06:25:01 journey-test python3[1090]:        0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            168.63.129.16        owner UID match 0
Jul 15 06:25:01 journey-test python3[1090]:        0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            168.63.129.16        ctstate INVALID,NEW
```

Any tips? How can I find, who has added this `REJECT` rules?

**UPD:** In **/etc/waagent.conf** I've found `OS.EnableFirewall=y`. On our old VM there is no such rule. And all new deployed VM has this rule. So, Azure has changed default behavior of this agent. And now it can change firewall rules.
And, I assume, it is the root of our problem.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about PROHIBIT or RESET chains. Gather tshark or tcpdump on all interfaces, especially on `lo`, in case this repeats.

Comment: @kubanczyk it repeats periodically.

Comment: @kubanczyk I thought I cant send local request 'cause of `RESET` record.

Comment: That does depend on the firewall setup. But the chains you posted provide no information if they are ever used. It could easily be that these are some default chains from apf.

Comment: @hargut I don't see any mentions about Azure fabric firewall rules in logs on VM where everything is fine. So, I assume, Azure fabric firewall rules broke our VM. Is it possible? Probably it has some default rules, that break network.

Comment: @hargut in `/etc/waagent.conf` I've found `OS.EnableFirewall=y`. So Azure agent changes our rules.